# Threading Condition Acquire lock is not actually acquiring the lock

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pandas, zeromq

I am trying to create a ZMQ Subscriber that writes to a CSV every certain amount of time (The time doesn't matter as much)

My problem im having is in my write class. When I'm run the c.acquire to acquire the lock it doesnt do anything and the loop just freezes

The c.acquire in my ZMQ_Thread class is actually working so Im not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any pointers or tips would be amazing. Thanks in advance.

```
import zmq
import pandas as pd
import time
import threading


c = threading.Condition()
df = pd.DataFrame()
s = 0
m = 0
h = 0
d = 0

def counter():
    global h,s,m,d
    while True:
        s += 1
        print("Second:{}".format(s))
        if s >=60:
            m +=1
            s = 0
        if m >= 60:
            h += 1
            m = 0
        if h >= 24:
            d += 1
            h = 0        
        time.sleep(1)

class write(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
    def run(self):
        global df
        while True:            
            print('sleeping')            
            time.sleep(12)
            c.acquire()
            print('acquired')
            print(df)                 
            with open("FILE", 'a') as f:
                    df.to_csv(f, encoding = 'utf-8', index = False, header = False)
            c.release()
            c.notify()
            z = zmq_thread()            
            z.run()        

class zmq_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
    def run(self):  
        global df
        print('DF Created')
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)      
        socket.connect("tcp://localhost:#####")
        socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'TOPIC') 
        print('socket connected')

        count = 0
        while True: 
            c.acquire()
            try:
                count +=1
                if count == 10:
                    print('ZMQ Break') 
                    c.notify()
                    c.release()
                    print('Lock released')
                    return df                
                message = socket.recv_string()
                message2 = socket.recv_string()        
                if message == 'TOPIC':
                    message2_split = message2.split(",")
                    message4 = pd.Series(message2_split)
                    df = df.append(message4, ignore_index=True)               
                    print('ZMQ Running')

            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break              



counter = threading.Thread(target = counter)
write_csv1 = write("Write_csv")
zmq_loop = zmq_thread('Start_ZMQ')    

counter.start()
write_csv1.start()    
zmq_loop.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this, is that I wasn't calling c.wait(). this is the code snip from my code that I added c.wait() where c.notify() was. It waits for the next process to acquire the lock then starts the write_csv class.

```
while True: 
            c.acquire()
            try:
                count +=1
                if count == 10:
                    print('ZMQ Break') 
                    c.wait()                                      
                message = socket.recv_string()
                message2 = socket.recv_string()        
                if message == 'TOPIC':
                    message2_split = message2.split(",")
                    message4 = pd.Series(message2_split)
                    df = df.append(message4, ignore_index=True)               
                    print('ZMQ Running')
```